# elasticsearch geo_point don't work properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make geo_point queries on elasticsearch but it doesn't work properly for me. I always get empty result for geo_polygon queries. maybe my mapping is wrong or the way i get the data.

1. mapping :

   ```
    curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/botanique_localisation/' -d '{
       "mappings":{
           "botanique_localisation" : {
               "_all" : {"enabled" : true},
               "_index" : {"enabled" : true},
               "_id" : {"index": "not_analyzed", "store" : false},
               "properties" : {
                   "_id" : {"type" : "string", "store" : "no","index": "not_analyzed"  } ,
                   "LOCATION" : { "type" : "geo_point","lat_lon" :true ,"validate":true  , "store":"yes" }             
               }
           }
       }
     }'
   ```
2. creating the view in oracle

   ```
    create view all_specimens_localisation as select RAWTOHEX( SPECIMENS.occurrenceid ) as "_id" , 
    decode(LOCALISATIONS.decimalLatitude ||',' || LOCALISATIONS.decimalLongitude, ',', null ,
     '{"lat":' || replace(LOCALISATIONS.decimalLatitude,',' ,'.' ) ||',"lon":' || replace(LOCALISATIONS.decimalLongitude , ',' ,'.' ) || '}'
    ) as location 
    from SPECIMENS left outer join ... where rownum < 1000 ;
   ```

i create a json object in the sql because sending lat_lon as a string didn't work for me ( elastic don't split the string as write her  http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html#_lat_lon_as_string_6 )

3. creating the river from oracle to elasticsearch

   ```
      curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/localisation_river/_meta' -d '{
         "type" : "jdbc",
         "jdbc" : {
           "index" : "botanique_localisation",
           "bulk_size" : 2000,
           "max_bulk_requests" : 10,
           "bulk_flush_interval" : "1s",
           "type" : "specimens",
           "url" : "********",
           "user" : "********",
           "password" : "********", 
           "sql" : "select * from all_specimens_localisation"
        }
   }'
   ```
4. exemple of indexed data in elastichsearch

   ```
   {
       _index: botanique_localisation
       _type: specimens
       _id: 38C8F872A449491C881791DE8B501B17
       _score: 1.4142135
       _source: {
           LOCATION: {
               lon: 47.05
               lat: -19.95
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. working range query

   ```
          curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/botanique_localisation/specimens/_search?size=10&pretty' -d '
   { "query": {  "bool": { "must": [
       { "range": {
               "LOCATION.lon": {
                   "from": 47.04,
                   "to": 47.08
               }
           }
       },{ "range": {
               "LOCATION.lat": {
                   "from": -20,
                   "to": -19.90
               }
           }
       }
   ]}}}'
   ```

   and the result :

   ```
   hits:{[
   {    "_index": botanique_localisation,
       "_type": specimens,
       "_id": 38C8F872A449491C881791DE8B501B17,
       "_score": 1.4142135,
       "_source": {
           "LOCATION": { "lon": 47.05, "lat": -19.95 }
       }
   },...
   ```
6. now the fun not working part ! with the geo_polygon query :

   ```
   curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/botanique_localisation/_search?size=10&pretty' -d '{
       "query":{
           "filtered" : {
               "query" : { "match_all" : {}},
               "filter" : {
                   "geo_polygon" : {
                       "LOCATION" : {
                           "points" : [
                               { "lat": 100, "lon": -100},
                               { "lat": 100, "lon": 100},
                               { "lat": -100, "lon": 100 },
                               { "lat": -100 , "lon": -100 }                            
                           ]
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }'
   ```

this return no hits !

what i'm missing ?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

this query work :

```
    curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/botanique_localisation/_search?pretty' -d '{
        "query" : {
            "filtered" : {
                "filter" : {
                    "geo_bounding_box" : {
                        "type" : "indexed",
                        "LOCATION" : {
                            "top_left" : {
                                "lat" : 50,
                                "lon" : -50
                            },
                            "bottom_right" : {
                                "lat" :-50,
                                "lon" : 50
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }'
```